# Unable to send post or put parameters using RocketPants client

Tags: ruby, httparty, rocketpants

I am writing an api client using the [RocketPants gem](https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants) and am trying to use HTTParty as included in the gem to read, create, update and destroy resources.

Reading and destroying works just fine, but I am facing problems creating and updating resources (in the example below, events).

Specifically, I am trying the following:

```
def create_event params
  post "events", :body => { :event => params }, :transformer => Event
end
```

But on the API side it always gives me

```
Rendering error for ActionController::ParameterMissing:
key not found: event
```

even though I do include it in the post request.

However, when I try doing it with HTTParty directly, like so:

```
HTTParty.post(
  "http://localhost:3000/1/events",
  :headers => {
    'Authorization' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("test token")
  },
  :body => {
    :event => {
      :name => "test"
    }
  }
)
```

it works, so it can't be the API that's not working. This approach has two downsides: I need to pass in authorization manually, and the result is not wrapped as an Event.

Am I missing anything to properly send post and put requests? I also looked at the docs and specs, but couldn't find anything on posting/putting (e.g., see https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants/blob/master/spec/rocket_pants/client_spec.rb).

Here is my full code:

```
require "ticket_gate/version"
require "rocket_pants"

module TicketGate
  class Client < RocketPants::Client
    # ---- Setup -----------------------------------
    # ----------------------------------------------
    version 1
    base_uri 'http://localhost:3000'

    def initialize access_token = nil
      raise 'Please initialize with your api access token' unless access_token
      @access_token = access_token
    end

    def base_request_options
      { :headers => { 'Authorization' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(@access_token) } }
    end

    # ---- Events -----------------------------------
    # -----------------------------------------------
    class Event < APISmith::Smash
      property :created_at
      property :end_at
      property :id
      property :name
      property :parent_id
      property :start_at
      property :ticket_limit
      property :updated_at
    end

    def list_events
      get "events", :transformer => Event
    end

    def get_event id
      get "events/#{id}", :transformer => Event
    end

    #### HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    def create_event params
      post "events", :body => { :event => params }, :transformer => Event
    end

    #### HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    def update_event id, params
      put "events/#{id}", :body => { :event => params }, :transformer => Event
    end

    def destroy_event id
      delete "events/#{id}", :transformer => Event
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RocketPants uses [API Smith](https://github.com/filtersquad/api_smith) internally for the HTTP requests.

From the [API Smith documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/api_smith/1.3.0/APISmith/Client/InstanceMethods#request%21-instance_method) I tried to figure out how to pass POST parameters properly, and I'm guessing this is what you're supposed to do:

```
post "events", :extra_body => { :event => params }, :transformer => Event
```